# Better Looking Select Boxes for Web App

Tags: web

For a web app I am working on, I am looking for a widget that works like (or implements) a select box that is much more user-friendly and customizable than the basic HTML select box. I'd prefer not to have to build something like this from scratch, so I was wondering if anyone knows of an open-source widget of this type that I could use.

An example of a more user-friendly select box which I wouldn't mind imitating is the calculator at this link:

http://www.teslamotors.com/charging#/calculator

Doesn't have to be identical to this, but something with more room for customization and a nicer looking UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many plugins and tutorials about customizing `select` tag.

These are plugins:

- http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/
- http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
- http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/#demos
- http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-gentleSelect/
- http://vst.mn/selectordie/

For that kind of `select` tag that you showed you should create your own style.

Here is good tutorial about creating customized `select` tag:

- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/
- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/